# how to get this view in math,(always appear like this)

Tags: front-end, color, syntax, code-request

How do I make math look like this forever?[image]

Comment: Have a look at "Preferences/Appearances/Syntax Coloring"

Comment: hi, Yes, but what colors to put, is there a color code?

Comment: Another option is to choose or create a stylesheet with your desired colors. ReverseColor ships with Mathematica. There is also a Dracula stylesheet on the web. Neither exactly matches the one you illustrate, but you can edit and choose your own colors.

Comment: @jdp , do you mean this one                                                 https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DraculaTheme  , would you be so kind to explain how it works, my english is not good

Comment: Yes, that's the one. There are others as well - I recall one called "Solarized Dark". Probably many more. They affect the overall look of the notebook. There is a tutorial in the documentation which does a far better job of explaining this than I can: tutorial/WorkingWithStylesheets. Once you install the stylesheet, you can edit it to suit your taste and save the new version. If you look in the Format menu for an open notebook, you can see a selection of available stylesheet which ship with Mathematica. There's also an edit stylesheet option in that menu.

Comment: If you happen to have the notebook which the image you posted is based on, saved on your computer, you may be able to edit the notebook's stylesheet and extract it for your own use, giving it a name of your choosing. Otherwise, you'll have to take another stylesheet and edit it to get the color scheme you want.

Comment: @jdp , do you have access to a file that makes the changes and the path where to put it, thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Stylesheets you download or create via edits are placed in $UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Stylesheets. If you open a notebook and use Format/Edit Stylesheet, the editor has an Export button that installs your edited version. If you download, say, the Dracula stylesheet from the link, it has instructions for how to install/uninstall it under "Details and Options".I.e.  ResourceFunction["DraculaTheme"]["Install"] , or Uninstall if you change your mind.

Comment: hi,thanks for everything